# Creating graphs of CNN models: cannot use plot_model from keras.utils.vis_utils

Tags: python, keras, graphs

I am using keras w/ PyCharm on windows 10. I am trying to print my tensorflow.keras.Model using

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
...
res_net_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs)
...
plot_model(res_net_model)      #, to_file='cnn_resnet_model.bmp') #, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

I am for some reason getting

```
  File "C:\Users\Zack's 2016 Tower\.conda\envs\tensorz\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 240, in plot_model
    expand_nested, dpi)
  File "C:\Users\Zack's 2016 Tower\.conda\envs\tensorz\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 79, in model_to_dot
    _check_pydot()
  File "C:\Users\Zack's 2016 Tower\.conda\envs\tensorz\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 28, in _check_pydot
    pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())
  File "C:\Users\Zack's 2016 Tower\.conda\envs\tensorz\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 2032, in create
    status, stderr_output))
pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 1. stderr follows: Format: "ps" not recognized. Use one of:


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have confirmed that graphviz & pydotplus has been installed by conda. I've also tried to installing graphviz as an executable that's within my path.

I've looked through similar postings such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886711/keras-runtimeerror-failed-to-import-pydot-after-installing-graphviz-and-pyd/36890526#36890526) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115412/importerror-failed-to-import-pydot-you-must-install-pydot-and-graphviz-for-p) with no luck: nothing matches my error. It doesn't even tell me what formats I should use (although [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1357) may have the answer). It shouldn't matter because atm I'm not asking it to generate an image. I have no idea where it is getting 'ps' from.

Comment: `ps` could refer to `PostScript`, a page description language to create PDFs, vector graphics and such. Do you have it installed? Do you run your code in notebook or via command line?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem today and stumbled upon your question. As it had no replies, I dug further and eventually found something that helped me. For you it may be too late but anyone else having this problem, maybe it helps if I document my finding.

For the background: my setup is Python 3.7 under Windows 10.

The keras function `plot_model` uses `pydot` which itself relies on `GraphViz`. Moreover, the error message `Format: "ps" not recognized. Use one of:` you see is caused by `dot`, one of the tools that belongs to `GraphViz`, which is called from inside `pydot`. After playing around with the `dot` tool, it eventually told me the following:

`There is no layout engine support for "dot" Perhaps "dot -c" needs to be run (with installer's privileges) to register the plugins?`

So, I fired up a new console with administrator priviliges and ran `dot -c`. This enabled `dot` to use its layout engines and this made the error disappear. After this,  `plot_model` suddenly worked for me.

Hope it helps anyone.